# How do i get the error code from sql server in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS 2008r2 package that is failing with a foreign key violation.  I'm trying to trap the error that appears in the debug window,

> "*The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "xxxx". The conflict occurred in database "xxxxxx", table "xxxxx",
>   column 'xxxx'.*"

I've tried enabling SSIS logging and also creating an event handler for the "OnError" event but the logs only provide the generic SSIS message

> "*SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method
>   on component "xxxxx Destination" (1458) failed with error code
>   0xC020844B while processing input "ADO NET Destination Input" (1461).
>   The identified component returned an error from the Process Input
>   method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal
>   and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error
>   messages posted before this with more information about the failure.*"

I would like to get the exact error to be logged (ie that this is a Foreign Key violation) instead of the DTS error.  How can this be done?

Comment: In your OnError, are you grabbing the content of System::ErrorDescription?  In our packages, we stick an OnError handler at the package level, catch anything that bubbles up, and stuff the System::ErrorDescription into an email to ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use an OLE DB Destination instead.

And just for the record, if you have a script task in the SSIS you can log the error using the DTS object:

```
  try  
  {  
      // your code 
  }  
  catch (Exception ex)  
  {  
     //An error occurred.  
     Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script Task Example", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);  
     Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;  
  }
```

[MSDN - Logging in the Script Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136131.aspx)

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions, i discovered that the data that is provided is different depending on whether i select the SQL server error log provider or the flat file provider.  the flat file provider only shows the error number with the generic message, while the sql server provider also shows the error returned from the oledb provider.  i'll also try the try catch method as well